# Mathematic hidden collision

Tags: actionscript-3, math, vector-graphics

[image: Example]

I'm working on a project that uses tile engine (self made), and my next task is to create an AI (besides other AIs that are done), this one is tricky because the AI should only spot the player if the player is in the AI's sight. Tried it with for cycles to after calculating the ranges (in tiles) [1 tile = 32*32].
Then I thought about creating an equation of a straight line. And here I am, puzzled in math.

Any idea how could I calculate if it's overlaps one of these "hidden" tiles?
NOTE that I want only use math!

```
TileInfo.tileData[la[floor(y / 32)][floor(x / 32)]];
//la -> array of tile positions, if it's >0 then there is a tile.
```

Comment: What should happen if only the corner of a tile is between the AI and the player?

Comment: Then probably still out of sight.

Comment: Are you comfortable with calculating the intercept of the line with a horizonal or vertical like, e.g. the upper edge of the row of tiles?

Comment: You mean the intersection of 2 lines?

Comment: Yes, but the intersection of a line with a vertical or horizontal line is easier than the general case.

Comment: Can you tell me more about interception then?

Comment: @Zhafur You can find the mathematical explanation on [Paul Bourke's site](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/lineline2d/) and some code that shouldn't be hard to port too. I imagine you can also find as3 code online as well. I imagine you can have lines described by obstacles and if any intersect the line between your enemy and 'hero' then you have an occlusion, otherwise, the enemy can directly 'see' the hero. That is, of course if the enemy has a perfect eyesight. You can make the enemy see within a certain view angle(range) for a certain length if you want I imagine.

Comment: The only problem with intersection, that I can't create a second line to make the intersection of them. Because it's possible that there is no blocking tile between them.(TileInfo.tileData[la[floor(y / 32)][floor(x / 32)]] returns 0)
And if I still make the intersection, then it triggers as it's a wall. No way to do it with intersection too. There must be an another way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the viewer is at position `(x1,y1)` and the target at `(x2,y2)`. Now, I am assuming that there is a set of `n` contiguous tiles along  along `x` and `m` along `y`. The lower, left corner of the first of these tiles is at position `(x0,y0)`. The size of tiles are `d` along `x` and `t` along `y`. Now the math:

The line connecting viewer and target is

`y = y1 + (y2 - y1) * (x - x1) / (x2 - x1)`

The tiles corners are at points `p1 = (x0,y0)`; `p2 = (x0 + n * d, y0)`; `p3 = (x0 + n * d, y0 + m * t)`; `p4 = (x0, y0 + m * t)`. Now the job is to find if that line crosses any of the 4 segments connecting two consecutive corners. Let's take the segment between p1 and p2 (a horizontal line) defined by `y = y0`. If you set this into the line equation you can find the possible interception `x` which I named `xi`:

`y0 = (y2 - y1) * (xi - x1) / (x2 - x1) + y1`

You can invert this equation and find the possibx:

`xi = x1 + (y0 - y1)  * (x2 - x1)  / (y2 - y1)`

Now if `xi > x0` and `xi < x0 + n * d` you have an interception for this segment. Otherwise you have a free line of sight.

Do the same for the other three segments whose straight lines are defined by `p2 -> p3: x = x0 + n * d`; `p3 -> p4: y = y0 + m * d`; and `p4 -> p1: x = x0`.

Note that when the segment is horizontal (`y = const`) you have to put this `y` in the line of sight straight line, calculate `x` and compare this `x` with the intercept. If the segment is vertical (`x = const`) then you have to put `x` in the straight line equation, calculate `y` and check if it falls in the interval or not.

A final remark is that you have to take particular care of cases where `x1 = x2` or `y1 = y2`. This are vertical and horizontal line of sights and may lead to division by zero in the above equations. The solution: deal with these cases separately.

Comment: Well, that escalated quickly. I guess it could work, but how can I calculate y without x which needs y0 which needs x?

Comment: `x` and `y` are arbitrary independent variables locating any point in the `(x,y)` plane. They **do not** depend on any other parameter such as `x0`, `y0`, etc. A straight line imposes a constraint between `x` and `y`. A generic straight line intercepts a horizontal line when its `y` value is the same as the `y=const` defining the horizontal line (similar using `x` for a vertical line). The `x` corresponding to this "common" `y` is the interception. That is what I did above. I just edited the text a bit changing `x` by `xi` at the interception. Hope that this is more clear.