# what causes as3 code to generate NaN as a result?

Tags: actionscript-3, nan

I have some collision detection involving lines of arbitrary angles that I can't know ahead of time.  I've set up my code to treat them as the form y = mx + b and whenever I create a horizontal line all of the fields come out as NaN.  My question is: What operations in AS3 can cause NaN to be returned.  The thing that comes to mind is that a perfectly vertical line will have a slope of Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY and I imagine that that could cause potential errors.  It shouldn't be on a horizontal line, but logic problems happen.  The point is, what causes NaN to be returned in AS3?

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite

    public class Line extends Sprite{

        var x1:Number, x2:Number, y1:Number, y2:Number;
        var m:Number, b:Number; //y = mx + b

    public function Line(x1C:Number, y1C:Number, x2C:Number, y2C:Number){
            x1 = x1C;
            x2 = x2C;
            y1 = y1C;
            y2 = y2C;
            if(x2 - x1 == 0)
                m = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
            else if(y2 - y1 == 0)
                m = 0;
            else
                m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1); //these calculations could be off....
            b = y1 - (m * x1);
            this.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Q: "Whenever I create a horizontal line all of the fields come out as NaN". Hmmm - that sounds suspiciously like divide by zero, doesn't it?  Q: Can you show us some code????  ALSO: look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12123047/mathematic-hidden-collision

Comment: Whenever you declare a Number variable the default value will be NaN, but it is probably not the case here

Comment: package {
 
 import flash.display.Sprite
  
 public class Line extends Sprite{
  
  var x1:Number, x2:Number, y1:Number, y2:Number;
  var m:Number, b:Number; //y = mx + b
  
  public function Line(x1C:Number, y1C:Number, x2C:Number, y2C:Number){
   x1 = x1C;
   x2 = x2C;
   y1 = y1C;
   y2 = y2C;
   if(x2 - x1 == 0)
    m = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   else if(y2 - y1 == 0)
    m = 0;
   else
    m = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1); //these calculations could be off....
   b = y1 - (m * x1);
   this.graphics.moveTo(x1, y1);
  }
  
 }
 
}

Comment: There's code for the Line class, formats weird...hmm...

Comment: You should edit the question and put the code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your code may produce a `NaN` right here:

  ```
  b = y1 - (m * x1);
  ```

if `m` is an infinity, and `x1` is `0`, then multiplying it should result in NaN and this is true not only for AS3.

- I would recommend you to never use a line equation in a slope-intercept form, that you're using (`y = Ax + B`), cause you cannot define a vertical line this way. Always use a general form: `Ax + By + C = 0`.
- Do not compare floats with ==, always compare floating-point numbers with epsilon. [might help](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). You can have problems in your code if `x2` is almost equal to `x1`.

Comment: I have been having trouble with the scenario involving your final point, could I get you to elaborate on the reasoning for that assertion? (for when x2 is almost equal to x1)

Comment: You mention comparing floats with ==, my coordinates for the lines are acquired using mouseX and mouseY, would using int instead be an option?  For reference I'm using the mouse to draw lines.

Comment: Using `int` would be an option, if AS3 guarantees the mouse coordinates to be integers. I do not quite understand what exactly you want me to elaborate on.. The main point is that comparing floating-points with == is not good, even in some "obvious" cases. For example, `sin(1.2)` is not always equal (==) to `sin(1.2)`, though their values may differ by 1e-16.... Can't find a proof for this. =\

Comment: Thanks, that helps alot.  Thanks again to everyone who helped me find this problem.

Comment: that very [proof](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/floating-point-arith2.html) I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a Number and don't assign a value, it will be NaN.

for example :

```
var speed:Number;
trace(speed); // NaN
```

unlike and int which defaults to 0;

```
var speed:int;
trace(speed); // 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the global [isNan()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#isNaN%28%29) function gives some examples:

- 0 divided by 0: `0/0`
- Square root of a negative number: `Math.sqrt(-1)`
- Arcsine of number greater than 1 or less than 0: `Math.asin(2)`
- String that cannot be converted to Number `"5a"`: [when parsing it]

Also `1 * someObject` or `1 + someUndefinedNumber` will evaluate to `NaN`

Comment: This is just a list of most common invalid operations in AS3 documentation. There are more in [IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic standart](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/ieee754status/IEEE754.PDF), such as `0 * infinity`, `infinity - infinity` when signs agree, `REMAINDER(Anything, 0.0)` and a few others.